# foreach array wise multi SQL query not working in PHP

Tags: php, sql, arrays, pdo, foreach

I am trying to execute multiple queries with the multiple selected checkbox value-wise in PHP.
I am facing trouble that my code is executing only one checkbox value-wise query and the rest is denied.

I checked on StackOverflow about this issue and I got lots of threads about foreach loop but in my case, it is not working when I am applying that.

Please help me, I am first time trying the foreach loop and so that I have a bit confusing about the same.
I have also the problem that I am not able not to validate invalid data through an array.
How I fix this? it only works for the first check value but I want all checked checkboxes.
I am trying to fetch data from the database of those particular ids which value I selected in the checkbox. and echo it in the array for that all query as I mention below-

*Sending Form Data format as seen in dev tool*

```
referenceID[]: PO0203211
referenceID[]: PO203213
```

**PHP**

```
$checkbox = $_POST['referenceID'];
foreach ($checkbox as $chk) {
    $stmt = $con->prepare(
        "SELECT  * FROM `table` WHERE `ref` = :referenceid"
    );
    $stmt->execute([':referenceid' => $chk]);
    $stmt = $stmt->fetchAll();

    $response = [];
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($stmt as $data) {
        $response[] = [
            "slno" => $i,
            "name" => $data['name'],
            "orderid" => $data['address'],
        ];
        $i++;
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Move `$response` to before the first `foreach` (or it will be overwritten on each iteration). Then move the `echo` and `exit` to after the `foreach` loop. If you have an `exit` inside the foreach, it will always exit the script after the first iteration.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What's the expected result?

Comment: I'll suggest to use another way. Here, if you have 100 checkbox, you'll perform 100 query. Maybe it's better to "glue" all the checkbox value and then perform only one query using a "FIND_IN_SET" or "IN" action.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank you.. Its work... Please give me chance to vote for you. suppose `PO0203211` this not available in the database how I show an error that `this is not availe in db` with for each loop.

Comment: @Peter you are right but could you help me how to apply your idea in my code. I am new and your function sound really tough to understand in my case . you are true - pls help me

Comment: There already is an  answers saying the same thing as I did. You can accept that one. If there is anything else you want help with, it's better if you post a new question than adding it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, when using `exit()` inside the foreach the code does not continue and only performs the first element.

**EDIT 1:**

Ok, I'm going to explain a little more in depth how to optimize this code.

You get "id" identifiers from checked checkboxes.

You can use SQL IN () to optimize this.

Look at this

```
$checkboxDivide = implode("','", $_POST['referenceID']);
$response = []; //Final Result

$stmt = [];
$query = mysqli_query($con, 
         "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `ref` IN('{$checkboxDivide}')"
);
while($stmt[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query));

//Delete empty last array
array_pop($stmt);

$i = 1;
foreach ($stmt as $data) {
    $response[] = [
        "slno" => $i,
        "name" => $data['name'],
        "orderid" => $data['address'],
    ];
    $i++;
}


echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: How I validate.. check if data in available in DB or not with foreach.

Comment: @Satyam I edit my answer, now is optimize only one query, You can check if it works correctly for you, in this case please mark my answer as correct :)

Comment: @Satyam please provide result, edit your question

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `exit()` function withing your foreach, which will terminate the current script. See [php manual on exit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php).

I am referencing to the

```php
foreach ($checkbox as $chk) {}
```

not to the

```php
foreach ($stmt as $data) {}
```

The script will terminate after the first loop of the first foreach.

Try moving it out of the foreach.

**Updated answer because of the comment from @El_vanja

Move your `$response = [];` array above and out of the foreach loop. This will keep the data in the array and not reset the array every iteration of the foreach loop.

Comment: Still wouldn't work, since `$response = [];` is defined inside the loop, which would result in only the last element being output. It would need to be placed outside and before it.